# Проверка на соприкосновение объекта Unity

Tags: unity3d

Возможно ли в Unity проверить, соприкасается ли **сейчас** объект с другим объектом?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html  и https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html

Comment: `OncollisionEnter / OncollisionExit` (начал/закончил)

Comment: @Lesh это я знаю. мне пока только конкретно надо сейчас. но спасибо.

Comment: Т.е. что-то вроде этого https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html ?

Comment: Примерно похоже на то что нужно было. Спасибо